# Is a SQL Server IDENTITY auto-incremented field thread-safe?

Tags: sql-server, thread-safety, identity

I've some questions regarding the SQL Server `IDENTITY` auto-incremented column.

Does someone know if that field is thread-safe?

Can I use SQL Server `IDENTITY` column in a multitask application that attempt to parallel insert some records with an `IDENTITY` auto-incremented column?

Do you have any docs link about that?

Answer (score 3):

It is thread-safe in the sense that every number will be handed out at most once. Numbers can be skipped, though.

This is a well-accepted fact. SQL Server would be garbage if this was not so. It is the *point* of identity fields to hand out unique values.

Be aware that you can circumvent these guarantees by reseeding the column. That way you can have it hand out whatever you want.

Also note, that an `IDENTITY` constraint does not enforce uniqueness of values in that column.

Comment: Numbers can be repeated though if the identity is reseeded. They are NOT unique and not guaranteed to be unique. I agree with the threadsafe portion but the uniqueness part is just not correct. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange yeah... I added a few words on that. Who would be surprised by this, though?!

Comment: I would remove that part of your answer because it explicitly states in the documentation that uniqueness is not guaranteed and is easy to prove.

Comment: You are talking about uniqueness when reseeding, right? I don't care about that case much. There is no other case when non-unique numbers can be returned.; I did not say the column values are unique. I said no duplicates *will be handed out*. You can insert duplicates manually if you want to. That's out of scope here.

Comment: Yes I am talking about reseeding. It bothers me when something is stated as fact like this and it isn't correct. Not a big deal at all. I wanted to make sure that it was clear that just because a column has the identity property set to true it does not mean the values are always going to be unique.

Comment: @SeanLange OK, I get it. To me this is an unintuitive concern because IDENTITY columns are most often used as a PK column. It would be an exotic and even devious schema design to add an IDENTITY column without a unique index on it.

Comment: I agree 100%. Not a design choice I would even recommend but it is certainly possible and something I have experienced in the field before.